# How to execute multiple async Tasks concurrently

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I'm confused by this code.
According to the documentation that includes this code,
it invokes each task which allows them to execute 
concurrently, and then awaits for them both to be complete.

I don't understand how the order of execution works. By declaring the task `var firstTask = DoSomethingAsync();` does this cause the task to begin executing? I thought it is synchronous without an await expression.

```
public async Task RunConcurrentTasks()
{
    var firstTask = DoSomethingAsync();
    var secondTask = DoSomethingElseAsync();

    await firstTask;
    await secondTask;
}
```

Also, does this code achieve the same result?

```
public async Task RunConcurrentTasks()
{
    var firstTask = DoSomethingAsync();
    var secondTask = DoSomethingElseAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);
}
```

Comment: @Igor so this code: `var firstTask = DoSomethingAsync();   var secondTask = DoSomethingElseAsync();` causes each task to be invoked and start executing? How would I do it synchronously, if I wanted to?

Comment: If you have new question "how to run async method synchronously" please ask it as question (obviously all standard requirements apply). It is not possible to downvote comment for lack of research...

Answer (score 6):

> `var firstTask = DoSomethingAsync();` does this cause the task to begin executing?

Yes. It had better! `DoSomethingAsync` promises in its name to *do something asynchronously*, so if it does not hand you back an executing task, then its name is a lie.

> How then does execution advance to the next line to invoke the second task?

I don't understand the question.

> I thought it is synchronous without an await expression.

Your belief is false.  "Await" does not mean "make this asynchronous".  Await neither creates nor destroys asynchrony; it merely manages existing asynchrony. `DoSomethingAsync` is *already* asynchronous independent of any `await`.  Again, *it says that it does something asynchronously*, so that had better be what it does!

`await` in your example is just `return`.  It means "return to my caller, and start running this method again at some time in the future after the awaited task is finished."  It's an *asynchronous wait*.

Think of `await` as being like `yield return`.  When you're in an iterator block and you encounter a yield return, the method returns, and then it picks up where it left off at some point in the future.  `await` is basically the same; just the mechanisms are slightly different.

Another way to think of it is that `await` marks a point where *the current method cannot continue to run until the awaited task is completed*.  Since the method cannot continue to run, it returns.

Again, `await` does not do anything *to a call on its right hand side*.  It's just an operator, and it obeys all the normal rules of operators:

```
await Foo();
```

and

```
var blah = Foo();
await blah;
```

are the same thing, just like

```
var x = Foo() + Bar();
```

and

```
var f = Foo(); 
var b = Bar(); 
var x = f + b;
```

are the same thing.  Await does not do something magical to its operands any more than `+` does something magical to its operands. It's just a special kind of return.

> Also, does this code do the same thing?

Please don't ask two questions in one question.  Post two questions if you have two questions.

The question is unclear.  The semantics of both workflows are that the task returned by RunConcurrentTasks is signaled as being completed when both its child tasks are complete, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Your statement "Think of await as being like yield return" really clarified async/await for me.

Comment: @OldFart: You can think of `IEnumerable<T>`, `IObservable<T>`, `Func<T>` and `Task<T>` as all being the same thing with minor variations. A sequence is "provide the next value when I ask". An observable is "provide the next value when it is available".  A function is "provide a single value when I ask".  A task is "provide a single value when it is available".  Same thing; all that differs is (1) how many values are provided, and (2) whether you are *pulling* the value or having it *pushed* at you.

Comment: @Eric Thank you for that comment about `IEnumerable<T>` , `IObservable<T>` , `Func<T>` and `Task<T>`. Your explanation helps to unify the relationship between the types.

Answer (score 1):

> By declaring the task var firstTask = DoSomethingAsync(); does this cause the task to begin executing?

Yes.

> How then does execution advance to the next line to invoke the second task?

It will run `DoSomethingAsync` until it hits its first `await` that yields. At that point, `DoSomethingAsync` returns a task that has not yet completed, and the caller `RunConcurrentTasks` continues to the next line.

> I thought it is synchronous without an await expression.

No, it's still asynchronous. `await` doesn't *run* anything. `await` will cause the consuming code to asynchronously wait ("await") for the task to *complete*.

You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

upon invoking the async method, with the parenthesys `()`, such as `DoSomethingAsync();` will begin the execution of the async functionality. It will return a `Task` immediately, which contains information about the async functionality being executed, and lets the system know when it is finished as well.

To run them in order, just await each one individually instead of awaiting the `WhenAll` call. As such:

```
public async Task RunConcurrentTasks()
{
    await DoSomethingAsync();
    await DoSomethingElseAsync();
}
```

now `DoSomethingElseAsync` will wait on the call to `DoSomethingAsync` before executing.

Comment: Why did you put such a dangerous recommendation to use `.Result` in an answer when it was not even asked in the question?

Comment: Well, he did ask about how to execute the task synchronously. In his comment.

Comment: OP should have asked separate question (really should have searched for answer themselves - there are plenty discussions on the topic on SO). There is really no good reason to just mention `.Result` without proper links to issues that this call causes. Would be much better answered in comment (or edit in comment into question first, but that would make already broad question way too broad)

Answer (score 0):

[Task Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The Task class represents a single operation that does not return a value and that usually executes **asynchronously**. Task objects are one of the central components of the task-based asynchronous pattern first introduced in the .NET Framework 4. Because the work performed by a Task object typically executes asynchronously on a thread pool thread rather than synchronously on the main application thread...

Here is your code annotated, hopefully this makes more sense.

```
public async Task RunConcurrentTasks()
{
    // starts DoSomethingAsync and returns a Task which contains the information about the running state of that operation
    // the thread that called this gets that Task as a result immediatly and can continue on to the next statement while this is running
    var firstTask = DoSomethingAsync();

    // starts DoSomethingElseAsync and returns a Task which contains the information about the running state of that operation
    // the thread that called this gets that Task as a result immediatly and can continue on to the next statement while this is running
    var secondTask = DoSomethingElseAsync();

    // suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes
    // only then do we proceed to the next line (assuming no exception was thrown)
    await firstTask;

    // suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes
    // only then do we proceed to the next line (assuming no exception was thrown)
    await secondTask;
} 


public async Task RunConcurrentTasks()
{
    // starts DoSomethingAsync and returns a Task which contains the information about the running state of that operation
    // the thread that called this gets that Task as a result immediatly and can continue on to the next statement while this is running
    var firstTask = DoSomethingAsync();

    // starts DoSomethingElseAsync and returns a Task which contains the information about the running state of that operation
    // the thread that called this gets that Task as a result immediatly and can continue on to the next statement while this is running
    var secondTask = DoSomethingElseAsync();

    // suspend the execution of the method until the awaited DoSomethingAsync AND DoSomethingElseAsync have completed
    // only then do we proceed to the next line (assuming no Exceptions was thrown)
    await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);
}
```

*From comments*

> How would I do it synchronously, if I wanted to?

[Await documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx)

> The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes

Use `await` immediately after each call, this ensures that execution does not proceed to the next line until a result (or Exception) is returned from the execution of the Task being awaited. *It does not actually make it synchronous in the technical sense of the word.* So take your 1st example and reorder the lines so that you call `await` after starting the first operation and before you start your 2nd operation.

```
var firstTask = DoSomethingAsync();
await firstTask;
var secondTask = DoSomethingElseAsync();
await secondTask;
```

which can also be rewritten as

```
await DoSomethingAsync();
await DoSomethingElseAsync();
```

Comment: We do **NOT** "stop execution on this thread".  The whole *point* of `await` is to **avoid** stopping execution on the thread!

Comment: @EricLippert - bad wording on my part, I re-phrased (also the phrasing in the code comments).